# How to get an existing feature's rotation angle in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers-2, openlayers

I created two external controls for my OpenLayers 3 map: Rotate Left and Rotate Right.
I already stored the last dragged/clicked feature in a *global* variable, yet I'm struggling to retrieve the actual rotation of the feature to "add" or "substract" degrees to it.

Here is what the code of my "Rotate Right" button looks like:

```
var evt = lastEvent;
if (evt == "") {
    return false;
} else {
    var coordX = evt.coordinate[0];
    var coordY = evt.coordinate[1];

    var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
        function(feature, layer) {
            return feature;
        });

    var layer = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
        function(feature, layer) {
            return layer;
        });

    // This is where I need to get the feature's rotation value.
    var rotation = Math.random() * 10 + 1;
    var origin = new ol.geom.Point(coordX, coordY);
    feature.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon( /** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
            anchor: [0.5, 0.5],
            rotation: rotation,
            anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
            anchorYUnits: 'fraction',
            src: 'https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pictype-free-vector-icons/16/home-128.png'
        }))
    }));
}
```

I've been browsing through the [API documentation](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/) and the examples but I can't seem to find a way to access the feature's rotation value once it's already drawn on the layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't if the reason that you couldn't find anything in the documentation, was because you didn't un-clicked the "Stable only" in the upper right corner of the API  documentation.

Try this:

```js
var _feature; // your feature
var _style = _feature.getStyle();
var _imagestyle = _style.getImage();
var rotation = _imagestyle.getRotation();
```

I haven't testet it, but give it a try.

Comment: You're right, I was only browsing the stable version of the API. I've concatenated your code in your simple line: `YourFeatureVariable.getStyle().getImage().getRotation()`

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternate way for those who don't want to run *unstable code*.

Since it's possible to store whatever data we want in the feature (ie.: the `name` property), why not add the rotation value as a property too? This worked for me:

### Object initialization

```
/* When you create the ol.Feature object, add some properties to store the rotation.

var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
     geometry: new ol.geom.Point([400, 500]),
     name: 'House 1',
     lotNumber: 54872142,
     rotationValue: 0, /* This one right here */
     opacityValue: 0.5 /* Added this one too, you get the idea */
});
```

### Value modification

```
var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,

function(feature, layer) {
        return feature;
    });
var layer = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,

    function(feature, layer) {
        return layer;
    });

/* Magic happens here */
var rotation = feature['o']['rotationValue'] + 0.1;

var origin = new ol.geom.Point(coordX, coordY);
var opacity = feature['o']['opacityValue'];
feature['o']['rotationValue'] = rotation;
feature.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon( /** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
        anchor: [0.5, 0.5],
        rotation: rotation,
        opacity: opacity,
        anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
        anchorYUnits: 'fraction',
        src: 'https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pictype-free-vector-icons/16/home-128.png'
    }))
}));
```